# How to pass data item defined at process to object in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have defined few data items at process level and would like to access those data items in my object. However, i'm able to get data item from object to Process using input/output parameters. But it doesn't work in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this:

1. Go to object studio and add input parameter at start stage of an object.
2. Go to process studio - Add action stage and select the object from the dropdown (where you defined input parameter in step 1) and you will see the parameter under Input tab
3. Now pass on the value or data item you want to call in object studio.

Thanks